# Regressing coffee beans in US to coffee beans in EU

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

We're trying to model two time series: a random walk (independent variable) vs. the sum of this random walk and a mean-reverting process. For example: coffee bean 100kg prices (EU) vs. coffee bean 100kg prices (US). The difference between these two can be seen as costs in the transportation process, seen as the mean-reverting part. Now we want to regress these two against each other. Through OLS we achieve, as expected, a coefficient of around 1. However, our results show a large amount of autocorrelation in the residuals due to the fact that transportation costs has high and low periods.

To remove this autocorrelation we have tried to make them stationary by taking first differences for x and y. After doing this, our autocorrelation is completely gone, but the regression coefficient now deviates from 1 (for example 0.6), which is counterintuitive as the prices are for the same amounts of coffee beans. As such, we lose the trend in our data. How to correct for autocorrelation without losing the trend in our time series?

Would using Newey-West standard errors combined with the OLS coefficients give an accurate alternative to modeling the autocorrelation?

PS: there are no known tariffs/taxes for importing coffee beans